# JS method binding with 2 different this

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have this small code:

```
ScenesController.prototype.viewAction = function() {
    this.flash = this.di.HelperFlash.hasSupport();

    this.$playerElem = !this.flash? $('#html_player') : $('#flash_player');
// the first click is just a sample, I need the same object in the Quailty Change method
    $('.scenes_view_video_quailty').on('click', function() { echo($(this));});
    $('.scenes_view_video_quailty').on('click', this.viewVideoQuailtyChange.bind(this));

};
ScenesController.prototype.viewVideoQuailtyChange = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.flash) {
        echo(this);
        echo($(this));
    }
};
```

When I'm clicking the link, I would need pass 2 this variable to the QualityChange method. One with the object (in the bind) and the other is the click event, because I need the clicked element too.

I was trying with the .on('click', {$this: $(this)}, this.method) solution, but dosen't work, the evend.data.$this looks a different object.

I need the same object as I have in the first click method.
(echo = console.log)

Comment: Juste use `e.currentTarget` from within the event handler to get the clicked element.

Comment: Oh, this is the solution for my current problem :D But not the answer to my question, I wanna have the full object in the non-anonym method. Thanks BTW, good idea! :)

Comment: Yup, I would need the full $(this) in the QualityChange method, but it is a different scope, this is the viewAction, but I wanna access the same this I have in the anonym method (the firs click line in my sample)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias the `this` that refers to the current instance as something else (traditionally, `self`) and use `this` to refer to the clicked element

```
ScenesController.prototype.viewAction = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.flash = this.di.HelperFlash.hasSupport();

    this.$playerElem = !this.flash? $('#html_player') : $('#flash_player');

    $('.scenes_view_video_quailty').on('click', function() { echo(self, $(this));});    
};
```

To call a method setting it's `this` reference you would use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), for example:

```
$('.scenes_view_video_quailty').on('click', function(){
         self.viewVideoQuailtyChange.apply(self, [$(this)])
});
```

Comment: My problem is with the other click, I need to pass both this to the QualityChange method. The click this and the object this too.

Comment: Good idea, but still not working :( I got different object in the method

 Object[a.scenes_view_video_quailty 247povs1_...d43a5c99]
getjs (2386. sor) ---------- 
[Object[Object { di={...}, flash=false, $playerElem={...}, több...}]]
getjs (2386. sor) --------
Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=441803473, több...}

Only the first one looks a real jQ object

Comment: @KrizsánBalazs I think you're missing the point, inside the called method `this` will now refer to the object instance and the single paramter passed in is the jQ object. (eg, insidide your method do a `console.log(this)` and a `console.log(e)`. The first will be the instance the second is the jQuery object

Comment: Yes, maybe I don't get the point, but without the $() the log(this) and log(e) will be the same obejct, I see in console. But I need the jQ object that I have in the anonym function (in the first click event).

Comment: I'm close, if I'm apply first the 2 this, and click the click event it is I will have both the the this but because of the applay the method running right after the call. :\

Comment: Not the exact solution what I want, but it is the closeset, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach any number of variables with `bind`
You could have a proper method like:

```
ScenesController.prototype.viewVideoQuailtyChange = function(secondThis) {
}
```

then use the bind as:

```
this.viewVideoQuailtyChange.bind(this, $(this));
```

With this solution you do lose the event though, so it might need some more thought. I'll look into it and update the answer :)

Comment: It won't work, because it is the same this scope, the only difference, the last one will be a jQ object.